# JSON formatting with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to build some JSON output for a JavaScript application and it's expecting the format in a very specific way.

At the moment I have successfully generated a JSON output from my php file. The problem I have is around how the use of brackets differs from what the script expects. Here is how I built the JSON:

```
// define my feed
$feed = [
    "mapwidth" => "800",
    "mapheight" => "600",
    "categories" => [],
    "levels" => [
        "id" => "canada",
        "title" => "Canada",
        "map" => "src/images/shops-map.svg",
        "locations"         => []
    ]
];


// grab our items from the database
$locations = perch_collection('Shops', [
    'sort-order'    => 'DESC',
    'skip-template' => true,
    'count'         => 10,
]);

//loop through the items
if (count($locations)) {
    foreach($locations as $location) {
        $feed['levels']['locations'][] = (object)[
            'id'             => $location['id'],
            'title'          => $location['name'],
            'about'   => $location['info'],
            "description" => $location['info'],
            "category" => "clothing",
            "thumbnail" => $location['image'],
            "x" => "0.3781",
            "y" => "0.4296"
        ];
    }
}

//ready to generate
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($feed, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

My output:

```
{
    "mapwidth": "800",
    "mapheight": "600",
    "categories": [],
    "levels": {
        "id": "canada",
        "title": "Canada",
        "map": "src\/images\/shops-map.svg",
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": "u-001",
                "title": "Test Shop",
                "about": "sdf sdfsd fsd fsdfdsf sd fsddsfsdf sdfsdfdsfsdf",
                "description": "sdf sdfsd fsd fsdfdsf sd fsddsfsdf sdfsdfdsfsdf",
                "category": "clothing",
                "thumbnail": null,
                "x": "0.3781",
                "y": "0.4296"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "mapwidth": "800",
    "mapheight": "600",
    "categories": [],
    "levels": [
        {
            "id": "canada",
            "title": "Canada",
            "map": "src\/images\/shops-map.svg",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "id": "u-001",
                    "title": "Test Shop",
                    "about": "sdf sdfsd fsd fsdfdsf sd fsddsfsdf sdfsdfdsfsdf",
                    "description": "sdf sdfsd fsd fsdfdsf sd fsddsfsdf sdfsdfdsfsdf",
                    "category": "clothing",
                    "thumbnail": null,
                    "x": "0.3781",
                    "y": "0.4296"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note where `"levels": {` is output. My script expects to see the square brackets followed by the curly brackets. I'm losing my mind on this. I think it's how it's handling an array if there is only one item, although that has not led me to a solution as of yet.

Comment: It expects one more level of array then you have. `$feed['levels'] = [['id' => ... ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the extra array levels in two places...

```
"levels" => [[
    "id" => "canada",
    "title" => "Canada",
    "map" => "src/images/shops-map.svg",
    "locations"         => []
]]
```

and when you add locations to the level...

```
$feed['levels'][0]['locations'][]
```